# Handling a single event as broadcast and round-robin depending on service

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, message-queue, event-handling, service-bus

I have Service A that publishes an event to RabbitMQ. I have two instances of Service B that will use the event to write to its database. I have two instances of Service C that will send the event data back to a client via websockets.

Only one instance of Service B should handle the event so data isn't written to the database twice.

All instances of Service C should receive the event as any one of them could have the websocket connection that needs to get the data.

How do I have some services handle events round-robin and some instances handle events as broadcast, do I need to publish the same event to two different exchange types?

Comment: have a fan out exchange. B creates a single work queue and all Bs subscribe to that queue. C creates a new queue per instance.

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I needed to get me on the right track 

Comment: let me type it up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Rabbit MQ you send messages to exchanges and route them to queues defined by the consumers.

So in your case you can publish your messages to a "fan out" exchange, which will send a copy of the message to all attached queues.

Your consumers then connect, defining their queue. So B can define a single queue which all Bs share and will pick up messages from round robin and C can use a random name to define a new queue for each instance of the service. Because the exchange is "fan out" all of these new queues, and hence each instance of C will get a copy of the message.